# Strip first x characters from a number and check it matches regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to strip the first 6 character(numbers) from a number, and check that it matches a list of numbers. 
For example, the input value of the number could be: 
`1234567891234567`

Therefore the first 6 extracted would be:
`123456`

I then want to check if `123456` matches: `123456|765321|988721`.

I know that I can extract the first `n` digits with the following: `\d{6}` but then I need to check that these first 6 digits matches one of a list of numbers.

Comment: `yourdata.slice(6)` store this in variable and then use it

Comment: I need to use regex in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a *start of string* `^` check for the regular expression.

```js
const regexp = /^(123456|765321|988721)/; 

console.log(regexp.test('1234567891234567'));
console.log(regexp.test('7653217891234567'));
console.log(regexp.test('qq'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have your 6 digits from the start of the string using `^\d{6}` you could use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and loop through the values:

```js
"123456|765321|988721".split('|').forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s === "123456");
});
```